# Select from multiple tables with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following MySql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT students.fname, students.lname, students.year_level 
FROM (students, teachers) 
JOIN teacher_subjects ON teachers.teacherID = teacher_subjects.teacherID 
JOIN subjects ON teacher_subjects.subjectID = subjects.subjectID 
JOIN teacher_sections ON teachers.teacherID = teacher_sections.teacherID 
JOIN student_subjects ON students.studentID = student_subjects.subjectID 
JOIN sections ON students.sectionID = sections.sectionID 
WHERE teacher_sections.sectionID = students.sectionID 
      AND student_subjects.subjectID = teacher_subjects.subjectID
```

Anyone have an idea of how to convert this into an Laravel's query builder? Thanks.

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
$student = DB::table('students', 'teachers')
                        ->join('teacher_subjects','teachers.teacherID', '=', 'teacher_subjects.teacherID')
                        ->join('subjects','teacher_subjects.subjectID', '=', 'subjects.subjectID')
                        ->join('teacher_sections','teachers.teacherID', '=', 'teacher_sections.teacherID')
                        ->join('student_subjects','students.studentID', '=', 'student_subjects.subjectID')
                        ->join('sections','students.sectionID','=','sections.sectionID')
                        ->select('students.fname', 'students.lname', 'students.year_level')
                        ->where([
                            ['teacher_sections.sectionID', '=', 'student.sectionID'],
                            ['student_subjects.subjectID', '=', 'teacher_subjects.subjectID']
                            ])
                        ->distinct()
                        ->get();
                        return view('teacher_class', compact('student'));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please read "How ask a Question section". Thank you very much. Stack Owerflow is to coding service.

Comment: Look into laravel eloquents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because of the `DB::table()` that only supports one parameter, you have selected datas from two tables.

You need to use `DB::raw()` for these two tables:

```php
$student = DB::table(DB::raw('students, teachers'))
             ->join('teacher_subjects','teachers.teacherID', '=', 'teacher_subjects.teacherID')
             ...
```