# Selecting from multiple tables in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to select some data from two tables, here is sql code

```
`SELECT users.name FROM users, friends WHERE super_admin= false and friends.friend_id=users.id     and friends.user_id = 4 and friends.status= 1`
```

I used sql to eloquent converter and it returns

```
`DB::table("users, friends")
->select("users.name")
->where("super_admin", "=", false)
->where("friends.friend_id", "=", users.id)
->where("friends.user_id", "=", 4)
->where("friends.status", "=", 1)
->get();`
```

but the problem is on the first line it seems that its impossible to write DB::table("users, friends") it was probably possible in some old versions of laravel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select from multiple tables with laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584959/select-from-multiple-tables-with-laravel)

Answer (score 2):

You can use DB::raw:

```
DB::table(DB::raw("users, friends"))
->select("users.name")
->where("super_admin", "=", false)
->where("friends.friend_id", "=", users.id)
->where("friends.user_id", "=", 4)
->where("friends.status", "=", 1)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Join statement to join the 2 tables

```
DB::table('users')
->join('friends', 'friends.friend_id', '=', 'users.id')
->select('users.name')
->where('super_admin', false)
->where('friends.user_id', 4)
->where('friends.status',  1)
->get();
```